# How to insert a jquery-ui DATEPICKER into a specifec div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm using Jquery-UI Datepicker "https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/" "I'm using it on two inputs" and when I click on an input and choose the date from the calender I want to make an effict on a sibling of the input, but I couldnt because the datepicker is created at the bottom of the html code. So I figured that if I could make it be created in the div that has the input I'll be able to control it's siblings.
So my question is "How I make it be created inside the dive that has the input?"

```
<div class="formss">
  <div class="first-input">
   <input class="input1" id="datepicker1" type="text">
   <span>place holder</span>
  </div>

 <div class="sec-input">
   <input class="input2" id="datepicker2" type="text">
   <span>place holder</span>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: You will want to use the `onSelect` callback to then effect other elements. Your example does not explain what you want to accomplish or what you want to do with the sibling. Please update your post.

Comment: Inside the callback, `$(this)` is the current datepicker element, you can then use jQuery DOM navigation functions to find the sibling.

Comment: how to use onSelect @Twisty

Comment: @IbrahimYousry what do you want the script to do when someone selects a date?

Answer (score 0):

JQuery UI Datepicker renders the calendar at the bottom. You don't have to worry about it because UI Datepicker provides every option to customize your input. You have calendar instance available. Below is an example, that makes the label of the clicked datepicker field to change color on selecting a date.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
    onSelect: function(date, inst) {
      setTimeout(function() {
       inst.input.siblings().css('color', 'red');
      }, 50);
    }
  });
});
```

Here `inst,input` points to the input field which is marked as datepicker field. Hope this helps you.